# Video Recording API for Android

Tags: android, api, android-activity, media, android-video-player

I was wondering if there are known video recording API where you record a video and POST it to the webservice.
Those who are in a specific channel can GET the video you just recorded and play it.

I was thinking of building a webservice like that which almost acts as Snapchat.

Thanks!